# What are situations that make DoE inappropriate

Tags: experiment-design

I'm sure that Design of Experiments (DoE) is appropriate to a system when it has low noise and high reproducibility, like a natural system. For instance, finding out the effects of temperature and strength on glass strength.

But is DoE applicable to a high noise, low reproducibility system like an economic system? For instance, effects of print and radio marketing on sales.

If DoE is not applicable, what statistical tools are applicable to find effects and/or optimize such system?

Comment: I think it might help to be a little more explicit about the sort of experimental design methodology you have in mind. Industrial experiments (whence the term "DoE" arises) are often carried out under tightly controlled conditions - something that might be "noise" in a shop-floor production process can be a factor set to different levels in the lab. -, allowing useful models to be fit on very small sample sizes.

Comment: Actually, I'm new to experimental design field, and looking a way to apply experimental design (if possible!) to marketing or operations in a company. So, are you saying that DoE arised from industrial experiments and can only be use in such situations?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that: experiments are carried out in all kinds of fields, & the general principles are the same. It's just that the particular abbreviation "DoE" comes from industrial statistics: if you read a book on that it might emphasize optimal placement of design points for many factors under low noise; if you read a book on clinical trials it might emphasize cross-over designs for just one factor under higher noise.

Comment: Just google "design of experiments in marketing" lots of interesting hits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimental design comprises all activites relating to the active elicitation of data, and thus certainly applies to the use of advertising when its effect is being studied. Note that what scientists call an "experiment", or more fully a "true experiment", marketers often call an "A/B test".

Comment: Could you explain how experimental design deals with the fact that advertising systems have high noises and low reproducibility?

Comment: On the contrary, I don't understand how either of those things would be an obstacle to running an experiment. Why would you think that principles of experimental design no longer apply in such a situation?

Comment: Let's say you do a full factorial experiments with 2 factors in a mom and pop store, to find out whether price and shelf location of a product affects its sales. That means we need to have at least 4 experiments for different combination of factors. And you'll do an experiment per week. But actually besides both factors, there are other factors not considered in the experiment that might cause the sales, e.g weather, traffic, seasonality, and marketing cost. This causes the high variability in the outcome and the cost to do experiments then would be really expensive if you want to repeat them.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be expensive (I guess that depends how much you're losing when the goods are cheaper). You're right that all those other factors can influence the outcome. But the virtue of a true experiment is that by using random assignment, we can detect a causal effect regardless of such extraneous variables. In your scenario, if you assign conditions per day, you can get 10 day-level samples in each of the 4 conditions in 40 days, which is about a month and a week.

Comment: Okay, so that's how random assignment comes into play.